# Images stretches on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

### Pictures doesn't behave the same on my phone compared to computer device tool.

As the pictures show the hight gets stretched in mobile browser.

on computer **|** on phone (iPhone 6s, same thing happens in safari and chrome)

[image]
[image]

#### HTML

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
    <img src="img.png">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.pic-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;

  /* needed for hover effect */
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

### Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Example on http://codepen.io would be great next time...

Try to remove: `height: auto;`